# React: Dynamic row failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I am not getting any response on click that executes the addRow() function. What's wrong with my code?

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      rowCount: 1
    }
  }
  addRow = () => this.setState({ rowCount: this.state.rowCount + 1 })
  renderRow = () => (
    <div>
      <Input type="text" />
      <Button onClick={this.addRow}>+</Button>
    </div>
  )
  render() {
    const { type, value } = this.props
    const { rowCount } = this
    const i = 0
    let rows = this.renderRow()
    while (i < rowCount) {
      rows = this.renderRow()
    }
    return rows
  }
...
```

I know an easy workaround that uses lodash's time. Here, I am trying to implement it using vallina js.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Instead of using `this` in this line `const { rowCount } = this` change to `const { rowCount } = this.state` because state object only contains the `rowCount`

Comment: @MuratKaragöz duplicate `renderRow`

Comment: @kumark infinite loop :(

Comment: @MuratKaragöz your not increment the `i` value in the while loop.Add `i++` in the loop and check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are replacing the same row over and over again. You should use an array instead e.g.

```
let i = 1;
let rows = [this.renderRow()];
while (i < rowCount) {
    rows.push(this.renderRow());
    i++;
}
return <div>rows</div>
```

and you need to increment your counter `i` with `i++`.

Comment: I saw 2 element when my rowCount is set to 1.

Comment: @Melissa94 Set the index to 1

Comment: this answer is good but it produces more problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420117/react-dynamic-row-strange-index-in-render

Answer (score 1):

```
addRow = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ rowCount: prevState.rowCount + 1 }));
}

render() {
   const { rowCount } = this.state;
   const renderRow = () => {
      return Array(rowCount).fill(1).map((row, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <Input type="text" />
          <Button onClick={this.addRow}>+</Button>
        </div>
      )
   }
   return renderRow();
}
```

**Things to note here**

`Array(rowCount).fill(1).map((row, i) => {})` will initialize array if `rowCount` indexes e.g, `5` and fill each `index` with value of `1`;

The other thing to notice here `this.setState(prevState => ({ rowCount: prevState.rowCount + 1 }));` is i take in the previous state of `rowCount` and add `1` to it to update the new state.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the `row` as array to push each new element into an array and render and increment the `i` value in the loop for increment.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rowCount: 1
    };
  }
  addRow = () => this.setState({ rowCount: this.state.rowCount + 1 });
  renderRow = () => (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={this.addRow}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
  render() {
    const { type, value } = this.props;
    const { rowCount } = this.state;
    let i = 0;
    let rows = [];
    while (i < rowCount) {
      rows.push(this.renderRow());
      i++;
    }
    return <div>{rows}</div>;
  }
```